# Google Earth Engine fails to export variable

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, reducers

I am exporting zonal statistics for 0.01-degree tiles in various locations in Africa. When I try to find the tile's 2010 percent forest cover from the GFCC data, I use a reducer function:

```
var gfcc_2010 = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/MEASURES/GFCC/TC/v3')
      .filter(ee.Filter.date('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31'))
      .select('tree_canopy_cover').mosaic();

//Mean pct FC per tile 2010
var mean_2010 = tiles.map(function(feature) {
  return feature.set(gfcc_2010.reduceRegion({
    reducer: 'mean',
    geometry: feature.geometry(),
    scale: 30
  }));
});
```

When I print `mean_2010` in GEE, I can see the variable produced, called `tree_canopy_cover`. But when I export this feature collection as a table:

```
Export.table.toDrive(mean_2010, "gfccMeanGroup1_2010", "deforTilesGEE");
```

The resulting table only has the tile ID and geocoordinates. Why isn't `tree_canopy_cover` exporting? Full code [here.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fsalem043%2FARC%3APrimary%20analysis%2FForest%20data%20Group%201) (I use 0.5-degree tiles in this demo code so that I can print in the terminal).

Comment: Your "Full code here" link isn't publicly readable. The simplest way to share individual scripts is to use the "Get Link" function — you could create a script repository set to public, but "Get Link" makes links that work for anyone by default.

Comment: That's exactly how I shared the code, so it's unclear why there's any issue.

Comment: It looks like you used “Copy Script Path” instead of "Get Link". “Get Link” links have a hexadecimal string, not the name of your saved script.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this, Kevin. I will use Get Link in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table exports assume that the first feature in a collection has all the properties of interest. If the first feature in `tiles` has no intersection with the image, it will not have the `tree_canopy_cover` property and the property will be missing from the entire export.

To avoid this, you can either filter the collection with `.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['tree_canopy_cover']))` *after* the `.map()` (so the non-intersecting features don't appear at all), or you can modify the `map` function so that it sets a value regardless.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. I am re-running now to see if it works.

Comment: It worked! Thank you Kevin!!